# How can I trigger Text selectable from an event or button click instead from pressing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm currently using for letting user to select and copy contents from a Text block

`<Text selectable={true}>some text</Text>`

The problem is that when using scrolling or tabbing to switch different Text block, or screen, the "Selection Action" is popped up too quickly.
The behavior is like whenever a user is scrolling or swiping, the screen does not get scrolled or swiped, instead some text are selected and the Copy/Paste action buttons are popped up.

I'm seeking that if the Text component has a delay option for triggering selectable, no luck, so my idea is to use the onLongPress function to manually trigger the selectable popup? is that possible?

In addition:
Making an variable to control the selectable from onLongPress event does not work, because it only sets the Text component selectable to true at long press, it does not instantly show the text selecting UI and Copy/Paste action buttons
User must release the press and repress it again to bring up the selection tools popup

Answer (score 0):

- here is an implementation [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/9458ht?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp9et3yo00072v6ijn1x1g9s%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp9et3yo00032v6i5mchq6v1%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp9et3yo00042v6iv2gdhp3k%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp9et3yo00062v6i7lo13d1f%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clp9et3yo00032v6i5mchq6v1%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp9et3yo00032v6i5mchq6v1%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clp9et3yo00062v6i7lo13d1f%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp9et3yo00052v6iokf67u0a%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp9et3yo00062v6i7lo13d1f%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clp9et3yo00052v6iokf67u0a%2522%257D%252C%2522clp9et3yo00042v6iv2gdhp3k%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp9et3yo00042v6iv2gdhp3k%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

**Let see how it work :**

- we have Text component which render selected text and copy action on click

```
export default function Text({ selectable, setShowPopup }) {
  const txt = "Text selected!";

  const copyTextToClipboard = (text) => {
    const textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.value = text;
    document.body.appendChild(textarea);
    textarea.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(textarea);
    alert("Text copied to clipboard!");
    setShowPopup(false);
  };

  const handleCopyClick = () => {
    copyTextToClipboard(txt);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {selectable && (
        <>
          <div
            style={{
              background: "#eaeaea",
              padding: "10px",
              border: "1px solid #ccc"
            }}
          >
            {txt}
          </div>
          <span onClick={handleCopyClick}>Click here to copy</span>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

- App component display `Long press`, press and hold mouse for 1000 ms,  we call  and  reset once user click on "Click here to copy"

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import Text from "./Text";

export default function App() {
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);
  const timeoutRef = useRef();
  const onLongPress = () => {
    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
      setShowPopup(true);
    }, 1000);
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span
        onMouseDown={onLongPress}
        onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
        style={{ userSelect: "none", cursor: "pointer" }}
      >
        Long press
      </span>

      {showPopup && <Text selectable={true} setShowPopup={setShowPopup}></Text>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, your implementation is for copying the whole text without using the Text component, which is fine if it does the similar, however, the original selectable option for React Native Text component not only copies all text, but also allowing user to select a range of text to copy. Bottom line, if I cannot find a way to workaround the Text component, your implementation might be the one to consider :)

Answer (score 0):

the `Text` component is selectable only when the user presses and hold on it for 500 milliseconds. This will prevent the selection popup from being triggered accidentally when scrolling or swiping

Preview Code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const TextSelection = () => {
  const [isSelectable, setIsSelectable] = useState(false);

  const handleLongPress = () => {
    setIsSelectable(true);
    setTimeout(() => setIsSelectable(false), 500); // Set it to 500 milliseonds
  };

  return (
    <Text
      onLongPress={handleLongPress}
      selectable={isSelectable}
    >
      Hello World
    </Text>
  );
};
```

Update Code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

function App() {
  const [selectionStart, setSelectionStart] = useState(null);
  const [selectionEnd, setSelectionEnd] = useState(null);

  const handleOnLongPress = () => {
    setSelectionStart(0);
    setSelectionEnd(1);
  };

  const handleOnSelectionChange = (event) => {
    const { selectionStart, selectionEnd } = event.nativeEvent;
    setSelectionStart(selectionStart);
    setSelectionEnd(selectionEnd);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text
        selectable={true}
        onLongPress={handleOnLongPress}
        onSelectionChange={handleOnSelectionChange}
        selectionStart={selectionStart}
        selectionEnd={selectionEnd}
      >
        some text
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi, tks for the quick reply, however, by setting Text component selectable value from onLongPress event does not brings up the "Copy/Paste" actions popup, nor to the text selection, it only enables the Text selectable on next press, therefore, user must release the touch and re-touch it again to bring the selectable popups, this is not exactly what I asked

Comment: I understood and updated the code above according to you

Comment: thank you again, however, I doubt Text component has onSelectionChange option? I see TextInput does have, but not the Text component